# How to automatically send mail on server error event

Tags: nginx, error-handling, timeout, unicorn

I want to automatically send an email when my web service failed.

These are the two error I want to receive notification of

- `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`
- `/tmp/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`
- And possibly 40X and 50X server errors

these errors are reported in the error log file (`/var/log/nginx/error.log`)

Comment: This would probably create a lot of mail for you if this error frequently occurs

Comment: @dvhh But my *head* wanna  send mail :(

Comment: Can you use cron job to have periodical report ? Web crawlers can usually generate a lot of 404 errors

Comment: @dvhh emh.... is your advise send log files periodical?

Comment: no your log file is usually quite large, setup a script in the cron job that would `grep` for those error in the time interval (for example the last 1 hour or last 30 mins if you want to  ) and send the result by email (and don't send anything if no error is found )

Comment: @dvhh OH!!!! Thx I apply your advice :)

Comment: Use zabbix log monitoring. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items Flexible and power.